# Vue.js: v-repeat not getting data from JSON array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an array of JSON items, and I am trying to use `v-repeat` to output it as a series of table rows:

```
<tr v-repeat="items">
    <td>{{code}} </td>
    <td> {{description}}</td>
    <td>
        {{price}}
    </td>
    <td><input v-model="quantity" type="text" size="4"/></td>
    <td> {{total = price * quantity}}</td>
</tr>
```

A row with empty cells is output for every item in the JSON - so Vue.js is not getting the property values, even though I have confirmed that they are definitely exist and I can get the values in the v-repeat if I do something like this:

```
{{items[$index].code}}
```

I am getting no errors or warnings.

This is the JSON output of my Vue data object:

```
{ "items":[{
    "id": "408",
    "product_id": "6",
    "description": " item description here... ",
    "price": "1210.26",
    "created_at": "2015-06-04 15:10:14",
    "updated_at": "2015-06-04 15:10:14",
    "quote_id": "32",
    "quantity": "1",
    "code": "PI0055"
}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not initialize the data object:

```
data: {items: []}
```

Simple mistake - but the fact that no errors are given, and the fact that you can still access the data in certain ways makes it tricky to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine for me:

```js
var data = {
    "items":[{
        "id": "408",
        "product_id": "6",
        "description": " item description here... ",
        "price": "1210.26",
        "created_at": "2015-06-04 15:10:14",
        "updated_at": "2015-06-04 15:10:14",
        "quote_id": "32",
        "quantity": "1",
        "code": "PI0055"
    }]
};

var vue = new Vue({
    el: '#tbl',
    data: data
});
```

```html
<table id="tbl" border="1">
    <tr v-repeat="items">
        <td>{{code}} </td>
        <td>{{description}}</td>
        <td>{{price}}</td>
        <td><input v-model="quantity" type="text" size="4"/></td>
        <td>{{total = price * quantity}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script src="http://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, just before seeing your answer I realized that I did not initialize the data object!

Answer (score 0):

And were would this

```
data: {items: []}
```

be placed in your code?  Top, bottom, middle?  Without the location, there's no solution.